# Can I integrate inside a SharePoint an external application using SQL Server?

Tags: 2013, web-application, content, server, integration

I have an external application of file managing using SQL Server as Data Bases.
For the front-end, I use "TypeScript" for the JavaScript "less" for the CSS and HTML5.
For the back-end C# with a web API and the Databases SQL Server.

I want to integrate this application inside a 2013 SharePoint site.I'm not an expert in SharePoint and I have no idea how to proceed. 
Is that possible in Sharepoint Foundation? SharePoint Server? 
Do you have any ideas about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to show your external system page inside the SharePoint you just need to use `page viewer web part` for more details check [Display a Web page on a SharePoint page by adding the Page Viewer Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527).

In case you need to integrate the SharePoint with your external system to read / write the data from SQL server database to SharePoint. so you will need to use `Business connectivity services` that available in SharePoint Foundation / Server for more details about BCS check [Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thank @M.Qassas for you answer. Seem that Business connectivity services is what I need.

Comment: you are welcome, Please Mark as answer if it helped you :) Thanks